# adding a new column based on a condition, using FIFA database

Tags: python, pandas

For this question, I am using a FIFA dataset. I used a slicer/filter on `df` to view only players with 4+ skill moves and assigned it a variable. I then took a quick snapshot using `value_counts()` for seeing which teams held the most players with 4+ skill moves. Ultimately, I would like it if I could preserve this view if possible because the ranking is easy to understand.

[image]

My question is: what if I wanted to add new column based on the condition that it gives me the count of 4-skillers for each row/club_name, and similarly, anther column giving me the count of 5-skillers. For example, let's say *Real Madrid* had three 5-skillers and nine 4-skillers. The new columns would each show the counts accordingly. What would be the best way to do this?

*edit: `df.skill_moves` is an int column ranging 1-5.

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple named aggregates like so:

```
fourfive_skillers.groupby('club_name')['skill_moves'].agg(
    total='count',
    four_skills=lambda x: sum(x == 4),
    five_plus_skills=lambda x: sum(x >= 5))
```

I have a different dataset than you, but the output would be similar to:

```
Out[52]: 
                         total  four_skills  five_plus_skills
club_name                                                         
1. FC Kaiserslautern         1            1                 0
1. FC Köln                   1            1                 0
1. FC Nürnberg               4            4                 0
1. FC Union Berlin           1            1                 0
1. FSV Mainz 05              2            1                 1
...                        ...          ...               ...
Wolverhampton Wanderers      5            5                 0
Yeni Malatyaspor             1            1                 0
Yokohama F. Marinos          1            1                 0
Çaykur Rizespor              1            1                 0
Śląsk Wrocław                1            1                 0
```

---

Another commonly done thing is to have percentages of the total for each additional column. You can do that like this:

```
fourfive_skillers.groupby('club_name')['skill_moves'].agg( 
    total='count', 
    four_skills=lambda x: sum(x == 4), 
    four_skills_pct=lambda x: sum(x == 4) / len(x), 
    five_plus_skills=lambda x: sum(x >= 5), 
    five_plus_skills_pct=lambda x: sum(x >= 5) / len(x))
```

Comment: Small suggestion, I'd recommend using the `int` type for your counts instead of a `float`.

Comment: @blorgon: much appreciated! I'm not sure how to force `int` in this situation. Is there a strategy for that you recommend?

Comment: I believe just `df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype(int)` after the fact. I'm not sure why it defaults to `float` in your implementation. Perhaps you could use `(x == 4).count(1)` instead of `sum`? I don't have a dataset to play around with to find out though.

Comment: this is amazing! thank you so much!! is there an article to read more on your methodology? i keep forgetting that group by is merely an ordering function and the "true" arranger is the function after it, in this case `.agg`.
i tried taking a stab at it while waiting and got a similar-not-quite output using `fourfive_skillers.groupby(['club_name'])['skill_moves'].value_counts()`.  (fyi im using fifa 21 dataset).

Comment: @blorgon: Aha, silly me. The dataset I had used `float` for that column. I have changed it to `int`, and all works as expected. Thanks again for your comments!

Comment: @Yves: you're very welcome! Here's the relevant part of the documentation (please note that this is somewhat new to pandas; the previous way was to use a `dict` or `OrderedDict` to specify the column name(s) and agg function(s)): https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html

Comment: @mechanical_meat sorry! should I edit the lambda functions accordingly based on blorgon's recommendation? `(x == 4).count(1)` though im not really sure what you two were discussing. my dataset is using int64 for the skill_move column. lastly, is there a way to sort the new output? or do i need to `.reset_index` + assign to new variable then sort accordingly (which i believe is inefficient)?

Comment: @Yves: ah, yes, please ignore the comments regarding changing `sum` to `count`. That discussion was only motivated by the fact that in my different dataset the `skill_move` column was a `float`. For sorting, yes, you should use `.reset_index()`. Happy coding to you!